# Вывод информации об ограничении количества символов "на лету"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, веб-программирование

Хотелось бы сделать такую же проверку форму для пользователя как на hh,
Когда количество символов превышает n, выводится сообщение, или показывает на сколько превышено и если стираешь символы то сообщение исчезает.

Рабочих вариантов не нашёл. Буду благодарен за помощь)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("validated").addEventListener("input",function(){
if(this.value.length > 13) document.getElementById("errorField").innerHTML = `Длина сообщения превышает на ${this.value.length - 13} символов`
else document.getElementById("errorField").innerHTML = ""
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="validated" value="">
<span id="errorField" style="color: red"></span>
```

Comment: Отличное решение. Большое спасибо, очень помогли. Что бы сделать несколько таких полей с разной длиной как я понимаю, дублируем скрипт и ставим другой id?